# GoogleMobileAds SDK updating

Tags: swift, admob

I am trying to update the GoogleMobileAds SDK because it says me that there is newer version like so:

> You are currently using version 7.13.0 of the SDK. Please consider
>   updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version to get the latest
>   features and bug fixes.

Since I am using CocoaPods, I ran the `pod update` but it didn't update it because I still see the warning. I even tried to run `pod outdated` and it detects that newer version is available but for some reason it still doesn't update it.

So I went to download it manually and tried to add it but it doesn't detect the latest version

Should I remove the old cocoapods version and then add the new one manually or what to do? And how can I check what is the latest uploaded cocoapods version they have?

Edit: This is my podFile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'myProject' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Its just a version warning,  Ignore it.

Comment: Don't ignore it. The SDK team is constantly rolling out stability and speed improvements, if nothing else. Can you post your podfile so we can see it?

Comment: Ignoring wasn't my plan :) I added the podfile.